# calling multiple functions with same instance in scala

Tags: scala

is there any way I can achieve the following in scala

```
with new Car() {
     examineColor
     bargain(300)
     buy
}
```

instead of

```
val c = new Car()
c.examineColor
c.bargain(300)
c.buy
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> val c = new Car {
     |     examineColor
     |     bargain(300)
     |     buy
     | }
```

Or:

```
scala> { import c._
     |   examineColor
     |   bargain(300)
     |   buy
     | }
```

Comment: +1 for the second option. The first will create a subclass of `Car` and execute the methods in its constructor, which may not be what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming those methods (`examineColor`, `bargain` and `buy`) are invoked for their side-effects and not for their return values, you can use the chaining pattern in which each of those methods returns `this`, allowing you to write code like this:

```
val c1 = new Car()
c1.examineColor.bargain(300).buy
```